# Получение данных из URL после знака # (hash) на сервере

Tags: url, ajax, php, сервер

Доброго времени суток Друзья! Продолжаю писать свою CMS систему, среди её "фишек" будет функция перехода в режим "быстрой навигации".

Режим быстрой навигации, это по сути реализация системы клиент -><- сервер :

1. Клиент заходит на сайт, обработчик на сервере принимает запрос вида "**?m:s;p:h;i:1;**", генерирует каркас(шаблон) и отдаёт.
2. Клиент получив каркас, отправляет новый запрос(**Ajax**) на сервер и заполняет принятыми в ответ данными необходимые поля.

Слишком растянул вступление для вопроса, но хотелось бы по лучше объяснить, что же я хочу узнать.

При переходе по следующей ссылке : **mysite.ru/?m=s&p=h&i=1** сервер получит эти данные через суперглобальный массив **$_GET**.

При переходе по следующей ссылке : **mysite.ru/#m:s;p:h;i:1;** серверу необходимо получить данные после знака решётки(#).

Всё бы ничего, есть вариант использовать **Javascript** и с помощью браузера передать эти данные на сервер, но есть одно "но", а если эту ссылку открыл не браузер, а например поисковый робот?

И тут собственно возникает вопрос :

**Как на сервере только средствами PHP получить данные из URL после знака решётки(#) ?**

Использовать функцию **parse_url(**) можно, но она позволяет обработать строку запроса, а не получить её.

В интернете по этому поводу мало информации, а где то ещё и видел, что средствами только PHP сделать этого нельзя.

Есть сервис от **Яндекс**, [Яндекс.Музыка](http://music.yandex.ru/), там реализовано аналогичное.

**Хочу дополнить свой вопрос :**

А можно ли с помощью **Javascript** превращать текущий URL в URL вида "?m:h;......." при этом не переходя на него, хотелось бы как то всётаки реализовать такую совместимость и для поисковика, и для пользователя, который захочет взять ссылку себе на заметку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему такое всё-таки невозможно.
Понимаю, меня тоже такой ответ не устраивает, но был опыт поиска решения.
Сервер просто не получает хэш.
Так что только яваскриптом его отдельно отправлять. Для поисковых роботов и прочих безяваскриптовых существ должны быть адреса вида mysite.ru/m:s;p:h;i:1;, по которым доступна та же самая информация без аякса.

Comment: ... или `mysite.ru/?m:s;p:h;i:1`, что проще.

Присоединюсь, лучше определять бота по юзерагенту и выдавать ему стандартные гет-ссылки.

А вот со ссылками с других ресурсов - это да, проблема. Бот будет вылетать на главную (если он без js, уже таких немного осталось).

Comment: нет, это чересчур мудрёно.
Ссылки должны быть простыми: mysite.ru/m:s;p:h;i:1;
По такой ссылке должна быть доступна страница.
Но если с js всё в порядке, то не составит труда на ссылки навесить обработчик, который запросит аяксом нужный контент, добавит в адресную строку хэш (или сменит его), и предотвратит переход по ссылке традиционным способом.

Answer (score 2):

> Как на сервере только средствами PHP получить данные из URL после знака решётки(#) ?

Никак, якоря являются свойством локальной HTML-страницы и не передаются PHP-скрипту в любом случае.