# Как в экшене можно получить абсолютный урл с хештегом?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Я использую ангуляр первой версии, и урлресолвер есть только на /, остальное разбирается на жс, в экшене на бекенде как-то можно получить параметры которые за #?

Comment: бэкенд это webapi? в контроллере есть ApiController.Request.GetRouteData()

Comment: Не, обычный мвиси контроллер, похоже что никак, браузер даже на сервер не отправляет, что идет за #. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346489/how-do-i-get-the-url-part-after-a-from-httprequestbase

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение данных из URL после знака # (hash) на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91693/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-url-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-hash-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать прочитать referer header. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer